# Asp.Net cache images but not javascripts

Tags: asp.net, caching, static

How can I cache only images but not Javascript and Css files?

Is there any sort of header to control which mimetypes to cache?

Adding some further explanation: I have the following snippet in place, on my global.asax.cs, so that at my development environment I do not cache the javascript files (or it would require me to restart the server everytime for a simple change). Since the images rarely change I wonder if there´s a way.

```
    if (ApplicationConfiguration.IsLocal()) {
            //do not cache content locally, to make development faster
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the end it turned to be a rookie´s mistake:

I had the (wrong)impression that there would be only one response from the server, while, as a matter of fact, there were several, one for each resource.

Thus, I just needed to create an extra condition to validate whether the given resource on the response needed or not to be cached:

```
  if (ApplicationConfiguration.IsLocal() && !ShouldCache()) {
            //do not cache content locally, to make development faster
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
            Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }


 private bool ShouldCache() {
        if (Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath == null) {
            return false;
        }

        return Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.IndexOf("vendor",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) !=-1
               || Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.IndexOf(".png", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1
               || Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.IndexOf(".jpg", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1;
    }
```

In this scenario, I kept cache enabled for any images and for my "vendor" scripts (thirdparty)